# Auto deploy tools for python application

Tags: python, django, deployment

I have a project implemented with Django, I wish to use a tool to help me deploy the project onto the server automatically. I know the fabric library can do it, but I want to know whether or not there are other tools that have similar capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the entire list here.

http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/deployment/

Answer (score 1):

Fabric is too easy.
http://fabfile.org

Comment: Fabric's not an automatic deployment tool. It's what you would use to build one. Depending on how sophisticated you want your deployment, there may be a lot of work to do on top of Fabric.